# Install newest security releases for python with pyenv

Tags: python, pyenv

How to I install a python version, for which only security updates exist, but no current Bugfix version anymore?

I use Python with Pyenv on windows and Linux. The newest python version it knows about is version 3.9.13. But the newest version in the documentation is 3.9.18. I can download it, but it now installer but Sourcecode. How do I install it with on Linux /Windows with Pyenv?

Comment: If it's not listed in pyenv then you can't use pyenv

Comment: Have you updated pyenv? It is usually up-to-date with a week difference, so updating pyenv should show 3.9.18 when using `pyenv install --list`.

Comment: What is the problem with `$ pyenv install 3.9.18`? I just listed the versions available to install (`$ pyenv install --list`
) and 3.9.18 is available...

Comment: @FJSevilla See my comment: if pyenv hasn't been updated by the OP, it won't show newer versions.

Comment: @FJSevilla,  The pyenv itself is updated and the package list, too. I can find 3.9.18 on Linux, also on WSL, but not on Windows itself with pyenv-win!

Comment: I see, I use Linux... It seems that pyenv-win only installs versions for which there is a binary provided by python.org, for security bugfix releases only source code are provided, so pyenv-win does not list them.  There is an open issue about this: https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/issues/529